# VS compilation output not an exe

Tags: visual-c++

I've got VS2015 running on Win7 which succeeds compiling a c++ project (a WebView2 demo), and the exe output to both x86 and x64 is not in PE format.

The first two bytes of the .exe files output are xC5C9 instead of the normal MZ.

so wondering if these bytes are recognizable to anyone as something specifically amiss.  Can't believe the first two bytes would be just random, but a web search turns up no relevant file format.

Config type == Application (.exe)

Target platform == 10.0.22621.0

Toolset == VS 2015 (v140)

No managed anything set, CLR etc.

CFF explorer just says unknown format.

Thanks.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Verify you can write, build and execute a simple C++ Console .exe "hello world".  Then try something more complex.  Finally, you should  be in a position to determine "what's different" between the "working scenarios" you've verified, the the "WebView2 demo" you're trying to build. But we don't have enough information to know "what's wrong".  And guessing from the first two bytes of an arbitrary file - as you've already found - isn't going to help...

Comment: I guess you mean a sanity check console app to make sure VS isn't broken, so I did this and it works.

tycheck\Debug>ConsoleApplication1sanitycheck.exe
Hello World!  


So maybe I should try adding the NuGet packages the problem app needs to this?

Comment: Oops, first think I'll change the target platform to the 10.nnn SDK I had recently installed.

Comment: Making that work just meant adding the right exe path to an up-to-date rc.exe.

Comment: I'll compare all the build command lines next .. but have to sleep a while.

Comment: Sorry to bother. I managed to get the MS C++ WebView2 demo (GettingStartedGuides\Win32_GettingStarted) to work after down- grading the various NuGet builds from their latest stable releases, so I'm saying to heck with this one but if anyone is curious  (from CodeProject : WebView2 Edge Browser in MFC C++ Application)   
(how could VS2015 write such a strange unrunnable "exe"? Or so it seems.)

Comment: Funny, taking another look at those ".exe"s,  they have the PE usually starting at offset 0x100 like an exe should, with a slight deviation from that in some builds, like 0x108.  Oh well.

Comment: The file offset to the PE header is stored in the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER`'s `e_lfanew` field located at the fixed file offset `0x3C`. There is no specific requirement that the PE header start at any given location, so long as the `IMAGE_DOS_HEADER` provides the correct offset. See [PE Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/pe-format) for details.

Comment: The question was mainly about the sequence starting at offset 0, because whatever it is, it does not pass as an executable:  not starting with MZ, won't run, and CFF Explorer reports it not to be executable, "Unkown Format".  The appearance of PE at the further offset just seemed to indicate that something non-random was being output, and going onward the rest of these files have an appearance that might be said to resemble executables, and at least something far short of maximum entropy.